# How to include [ ] (square brackets) while naming a GitHub Repo?

Tags: git, github

Recently I was trying to name a repo like **[WORK IN PROGRESS]** Repo Name. But as soon as I enter **[** it is getting converted to **-** . How to solve this ?

Comment: There are quite a few characters that GitHub doesn't not permit in a repository name; `[` and `]` are two of them. Pick a different name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub restricts the valid characters you can have in a repository name.  In general, you don't want to use square brackets in a repository name because they must be escaped in a URL, and so it makes it hard to work with remote URLs.  You also don't want to use spaces, since they both must be escaped in URLs and are a hassle on Unix command lines.

GitHub has the concept of a description that you can set to include the phrase “work in progress” if you like; you can set that through the web interface.  Just set your repository name to something that you would call it if it were not in progress, and then when it's production ready, you can edit the description.